# How could 3D Bioprinting and Synthetic Biology be used for reproduction?

Tags: biology, genetics, genetic-engineering

I think it will be possible in the far future to take a single person`s cells, genetically enhance and change them using genetic engineering and synthetic biology using new genes, and put it in a 3d bioprinter in order to create a new person.

3D bioprinting could create a fully grown person instead of an artificial womb, which would grow a fetus and the person would be born as a baby like typical humans. With a bioprinter, the new person could be born as an adult. I think if this technology became possible many people would opt to create fully grown offspring because it would be much cheaper than to raise a baby until adulthood.

There is a video in the movie The fifth element which Leeloo is created from a few cells:

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-uvOpMyPgI)

Comment: "do you think x" is a call for opinions. We prefer measurable answers.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: Can you specify what answers should be addressing here? You've given context, now where do you want us to take it?

Comment: Are you asking us whether this is possible, or are you asking us what the consequences will be if it is possible?

Answer (score 4):

### Bioprinting can't make full humans.

This site [has already addressed](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/24007/is-an-artificial-womb-feasible) the feasibility of artificial wombs, and the consensus seems to be that meeting the chemical needs of a developing fetus using a machine is plausible. It will likely always be more expensive than natural birth, but it is definitely plausible.

Bioprinting, on the other hand, can't create a fully-formed human because we are so, so, so complex. It is possible to create sheets of some tissues, like skin, and some organs like the [heart](https://www.technologynetworks.com/cell-science/articles/bioprinting-organs-a-future-alternative-to-organ-donation-323422) are now the subject of research. However, we struggle to integrate basic infrastructure like nerves and blood vessels into the organs we make. This is because 3D printing operates vastly differently than biological development. You can't build a person starting at their feet and adding layers until you reach the top of their head; complex blood vessels need to be interwoven to reach **tens of trillions** of cells, nerves have to reach every tissue, and half of what you're interacting with needs to be filled with some type of liquid. If you somehow manage to build veins in layers, try keeping  bacteria out of them before the immune system is formed.

Building the body one tissue at a time and weaving them together would be a better start, but even that can't produce complex structures like the brain. Adult brains are the result of decades of forging and pruning neural pathways; even if we could safely weave together tens of billions of neurons, we couldn't create anything meaningful. Even if we somehow understood how to make functional brains, what about education? It's notoriously easy to learn new languages as a child because your brain is developing - whereas it gets difficult with age. Would 3D-printed adult brains be able to learn how to be human? Becoming an adult, both emotionally and physically/structurally, is arguably only possible through experiencing adolescence.

Even if you handwave the engineering problems and say it's possible - what about the cost? The only cost of growing a human in an artificial womb is nutrients; biology will form everything on its own. On the other hand, creating an entire human being manually, from scratch, must cost billions.

Perhaps bioprinting will revolutionize healthcare, but it will never allow for reproduction.

Comment: If an entire organ can be created using bioprinting why could not an entire person be created using the same technology?

Comment: @SabrineCrystalSantos Read the answer. `we struggle to integrate basic infrastructure like nerves and blood vessels into the organs we make` ... `one tissue at a time... can't produce complex structures like the brain` ... `creating an entire human being manually... must cost billions`. There's at least three explanations as to why not.

Answer (score 0):

**This isn't feasible, regardless of technological ability.**

Childhood is necessary to produce a functioning human being. If you just gave birth to a fully grown adult, they would still have no idea how to physically do anything, even as simple as lift their head like a baby. Children also learn much more quickly because their brains are still growing. This would especially affect how difficult it would be just to teach them language from scratch. Plus, not only would they not learn as well, but their larger bodies would consume more nutrients, making them more expensive over time.

On top of being less intelligent, they would likely just be physically less capable because their brains and muscles didn't grow into the natural neural pathways that allow us to access muscle memory. Early childhood is when the body learns fine motor skills, and the habits and strengths we build as we grow essentially lay the parameters for what we can physically do even into adulthood.

The development of our immune and digestive systems as we grow up is also a major aspect as to how our adult bodies deal with bacteria. Newborns rely heavily on the immunities past to them from their mothers. If they are just grown without that, the body would be incredibly vulnerable to disease immediately after "birth".

To summarize, a bio-printed adult would be:

- Mentally less intuitive/flexible.
- More costly to care for until they develop basic abilities.
- Physically less capable.
- Highly susceptible to disease.
- Probably a lot more downsides I didn't bother to go into.

You basically grew yourself a vegetable...

Comment: Bit do you think this technology could be feasible in the fat future for exemple in the year 2200?

Comment: Could not the artifitial grown new person be programmed to know everything?

Comment: @SabrineCrystalSantos If you could, why would you bother with replicating the human body? If you can artificially create an entire human psychy you might as well upload it into a robot with replaceable parts, inhuman strength and durability, and the ability to think as fast as a computer. Or if you want to stick to organics, make all of your people essentially super soldiers. At that point they aren't much different from clones anyway, because a lot of how our adult bodies form is determined by how we grow, even between twins. Without that you might as well make everyone the same...